# (LARAVEL) Two ORDER BY and a LIMIT

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

This is some sorting:

1. Get 20 posts sorted by "views".
2. AFTER IT FINISH, then go to the next step.
3. sort it by "created_at".

How to do it?

Heres my current code (which work, but I dont want to use SORTBY) for some reason sortby is not working for other project. if possible i want it to be as one eloquent query:

```
$this->data['today_post'] = Posts::orderBy('views', 'desc')->whereRaw('created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')->limit(20)->get();
$this->data['today_post'] = $this->data['today_post']->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

This code is not working, because LIMIT is usually applied as the last operation, so the result will first be sorted by "views" and "created_at" and then limited to 20. I dont want that. I want to sort and limit then after all is complete. I want to sort again the last time.

```
$this->data['today_post'] = Posts::orderBy('views', 'desc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->whereRaw('created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')->limit(20)->get();
```

Thank you so much

Comment: With plain SQL you can do an sub-query for things like that, but dont know how eloqent does stuff like that. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM abc WHERE a=b ORDER BY date ASC) ORDER BY xyz ASC `

Comment: I don't understand how it's different. If you sort by `views` and then `created_at` and take 20 you're more or less taking the same ones. The only difference is if the 20th spot is a tie and in that case if you don't sort by created at you're getting an undefined order.

Answer (score 1):

You'll still need to use `sortBy()` or `sortByDesc()` if you want to use Eloquent. I've just tested this solution and it works perfectly:

```
Posts::orderBy('views', 'desc')
     ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay())
     ->take(20)
     ->get()
     ->sortByDesc('created_at');
```